# Orientable rank two vector bundle over a smooth manifold has a complex structure

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, complex-geometry, vector-bundles

How can we show that if $E\to M$ is a smooth orientable rank two vector bundle over a smooth manifold then $E$ has a complex structure?

This is Exercise 2.3 of [https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/~wendl/pub/rationalRuled.pdf](https://www.mathematik.hu-berlin.de/%7Ewendl/pub/rationalRuled.pdf), and above the statement it is written that this exercise depends on the fact that certain spaces of complex structures are nonempty and contractible. But I have no idea about what does "certain space" mean here. Any hints?

Comment: Do you know how to construct smooth metrics on vector bundles using a partition of unity?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes I think I do